# @PostConstruct called multiple times

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have a Perspective Switcher Toolbar that I have added as a tool control to my `e4xmi` file (`Windows -> Trimmed Window -> TrimBars -> Window Trim -> Tool Control`).
I've annotated a method with `@PostConstruct`. This successfully gets called and passes the parent `Composite` in.

```
@PostConstruct
private void postConstruct(final Composite parent)
{   
    // Do Something
}
```

The problem I'm having is that this is being called twice.
The first time it calls the constructor and creates a new instance. It then disposes it straight after and throws a widget is disposed exception.
The second time it is called it generates another instance. The toolbar correctly and adds it to the GUI as expected.

This is an RCP 3 application running in the RCP 4 compatibility mode. I've added the `e4xmi` file and pointed at it using `applicationXMI` in the `plugin.xml` file.

I've read a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690586/constructor-of-part-is-being-called-twice) although I feel their solution may be different to what can help me.

Why is it being constructed twice?

**Update**
I've noticed this only happens if I clear the cache first by setting the `Clear` checkbox in the run configuration. If I don't clear the cache it only calls it once.

Comment: I have several tool controls in both the application.e4xmi and fragments and the postconstruct is not called twice. Where exactly in the e4xmi is the tool control - is this in a TrimBar, a part Tool Bar, or somewhere else?

Comment: The TrimBar. `Windows -> Trimmed Window -> TrimBars -> Window Trim -> Tool Control`. I've updated the question.

Comment: I've noticed this only happens if I clear the cache first by setting the `Clear` checkbox in the run configuration.